# Radiative Transfer Equation: What's "multiple scattering"?

Tags: scattering

> In the presence of multiple scattering, the radiative transfer equation cannot be solved analytically.

But what's multiple scattering?

Particularly if the RTE has the scatter coefficient, say, $\mu_s(x)$

then is this "multiple scattering"? Or would one e.g. have to have several $\mu_s(x)$ terms? Or be in some higher $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: have a look here  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattering#Single_and_multiple_scattering  also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_scattering_theory . You have to give a context/link as you will see in the links that there are various uses of the term